# Nine-puzzle game breaks on tile alignment

Tags: javascript

I'm currently doing a puzzle game just for fun. I'm sure everybody knows how this works, so I can probably skip the explanation.

I can move a tile just fine the first two times. However, the board breaks after that.

The `idx` property should point to the position in the grid. 0 for top left and 8 for bottom right. The `x` and `y` coordinates are basically the same thing, but I only use those for css positioning.

A random tile is picked and is not rendered. My idea was that I'd swap the coordinates and `idx` of the tile you click on, with the hidden tile. However, it didn't quite work as expected and after hours of searching I think I need a pair of new eyes to help me spot my error.

The problem is when you click on a tile to move it, so somewhere in `moveTile()`...

```js
class NinePuzzle extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    let q = [["0% 0%"], ["0% 50%"], ["0% 100%"], ["50% 0%"], ["50% 50%"], ["50% 100%"], ["100% 0%"], ["100% 50%"], ["100% 100%"]];
    this.removedTileIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    this.state = {
     bg: "https://media.wired.com/photos/595693e45992c54331ac2031/1:1/w_2400,c_limit/Porsche911_HP.jpg",
      tilesArr: [
       {idx: 0, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*9), 1)[0], x: 0, y: 0},
        {idx: 1, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*8), 1)[0], x: 33.333, y: 0},
        {idx: 2, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*7), 1)[0], x: 66.666, y: 0},
        {idx: 3, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*6), 1)[0], x: 0, y: 33.333},
        {idx: 4, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*5), 1)[0], x: 33.333, y: 33.333},
        {idx: 5, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*4), 1)[0], x: 66.666, y: 33.333},
        {idx: 6, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*3), 1)[0], x: 0, y: 66.666},
        {idx: 7, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*2), 1)[0], x: 33.333, y: 66.666},
        {idx: 8, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*1), 1)[0], x: 66.666, y: 66.666},
      ],
      noTileIdx: this.removedTileIdx,
    };
  }
  
  moveTile = (selectedIdx) => {
   let flag = false;
   let {noTileIdx} = this.state;
   let arr = this.state.tilesArr.slice();
    
    let selectedTile = Object.assign({}, arr[selectedIdx]);
    let hiddenTile = Object.assign({}, arr[noTileIdx]);
    
    let hX = hiddenTile.x;
    let hY = hiddenTile.y;
    
    if(noTileIdx+1 == selectedIdx || noTileIdx-1 == selectedIdx) {
     hiddenTile.x = selectedTile.x;
      selectedTile.x = hX;
      flag = true;
    } else if(noTileIdx+3 == selectedIdx || noTileIdx-3 == selectedIdx) {
     hiddenTile.y = selectedTile.y;
      selectedTile.y = hY;
      flag = true;
    }
    if(!flag) return;
    
    selectedTile.idx = noTileIdx;    
    hiddenTile.idx = selectedIdx;

    arr[selectedIdx] = selectedTile;    
    arr[noTileIdx] = hiddenTile;
    
    this.setState({tilesArr: arr, noTileIdx: selectedIdx});
  }
  
  render() {
   return(
     <div className="board">
        {this.state.tilesArr.map(
         (item, i) => {
           if(i === this.removedTileIdx) return null;
           return (
             <div
                key={item.idx}
                onClick={this.moveTile.bind(this, item.idx)}
                style={{
                 backgroundImage: "url('"+ this.state.bg +"')",
                 backgroundPosition: item.bgPos,
                 left: item.x + "%",
                 top: item.y + "%"
               }}
              />
            );
          }
        )}
     </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<NinePuzzle />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.board {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #5F5F22;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #FFFFC2;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.board div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top .25s, left .25s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have two notions of which tile to hide: `removedTileIdx` and `noTileIdx`, and your `moveTile` function only updates `noTileIdx`. You should really only use one, but for a quick fix, update both:

   ```
   this.setState({tilesArr: arr, noTileIdx: selectedIdx});
   this.removedTileIdx = selectedIdx;
   ```
2. You have two notions of which index in the tile array you're considering: the tile object's `idx` property and its actual location in the array. The way you update the second is backwards. So instead of

   ```
   selectedTile.idx = noTileIdx;    
   hiddenTile.idx = selectedIdx;

   arr[selectedIdx] = selectedTile;
   arr[noTileIdx] = hiddenTile;
   ```

   you want

   ```
   selectedTile.idx = noTileIdx;    
   hiddenTile.idx = selectedIdx;

   arr[selectedIdx] = hiddenTile;    
   arr[noTileIdx] = selectedTile;
   ```

   Again, synchronizing these two things is is an arbitrary constraint on correctness, and it'd be best to get rid of it.
3. Your condition

   ```
   noTileIdx+1 == selectedIdx || noTileIdx-1 == selectedIdx
   ```

   allows you to swap the hidden and selected tiles when they are horizontally adjacent, *even in the word-wrap sense*. This isn't what you want. You really want

   ```
   ((noTileIdx + 1) % 3 != 0 && (noTileIdx + 1) == selectedIdx) ||
   ((noTileIdx + 1) % 3 != 1 && (noTileIdx - 1) == selectedIdx)
   ```

These three changes made the tiles move as expected for me.

```js
class NinePuzzle extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    let q = [["0% 0%"], ["0% 50%"], ["0% 100%"], ["50% 0%"], ["50% 50%"], ["50% 100%"], ["100% 0%"], ["100% 50%"], ["100% 100%"]];
    this.removedTileIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    this.state = {
     bg: "https://media.wired.com/photos/595693e45992c54331ac2031/1:1/w_2400,c_limit/Porsche911_HP.jpg",
      tilesArr: [
       {idx: 0, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*9), 1)[0], x: 0, y: 0},
        {idx: 1, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*8), 1)[0], x: 33.333, y: 0},
        {idx: 2, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*7), 1)[0], x: 66.666, y: 0},
        {idx: 3, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*6), 1)[0], x: 0, y: 33.333},
        {idx: 4, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*5), 1)[0], x: 33.333, y: 33.333},
        {idx: 5, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*4), 1)[0], x: 66.666, y: 33.333},
        {idx: 6, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*3), 1)[0], x: 0, y: 66.666},
        {idx: 7, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*2), 1)[0], x: 33.333, y: 66.666},
        {idx: 8, bgPos: q.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*1), 1)[0], x: 66.666, y: 66.666},
      ],
      noTileIdx: this.removedTileIdx,
    };
  }
  
  moveTile = (selectedIdx) => {
   let flag = false;
   let {noTileIdx} = this.state;
   let arr = this.state.tilesArr.slice();
    
    let selectedTile = Object.assign({}, arr[selectedIdx]);
    let hiddenTile = Object.assign({}, arr[noTileIdx]);
    
    let hX = hiddenTile.x;
    let hY = hiddenTile.y;
    
    if(((noTileIdx + 1) % 3 != 0 && (noTileIdx + 1) == selectedIdx) ||
((noTileIdx + 1) % 3 != 1 && (noTileIdx - 1) == selectedIdx)) {
     hiddenTile.x = selectedTile.x;
      selectedTile.x = hX;
      flag = true;
    } else if(noTileIdx+3 == selectedIdx || noTileIdx-3 == selectedIdx) {
     hiddenTile.y = selectedTile.y;
      selectedTile.y = hY;
      flag = true;
    }
    if(!flag) return;
    
    selectedTile.idx = noTileIdx;    
    hiddenTile.idx = selectedIdx;

    arr[selectedIdx] = hiddenTile;    
    arr[noTileIdx] = selectedTile;
    
    this.removedTileIdx = selectedIdx;
    this.setState({tilesArr: arr, noTileIdx: selectedIdx});
  }
  
  render() {
   return(
     <div className="board">
        {this.state.tilesArr.map(
         (item, i) => {
           if(i === this.removedTileIdx) return null;
           return (
             <div
                key={item.idx}
                onClick={this.moveTile.bind(this, item.idx)}
                style={{
                 backgroundImage: "url('"+ this.state.bg +"')",
                 backgroundPosition: item.bgPos,
                 left: item.x + "%",
                 top: item.y + "%"
               }}
              />
            );
          }
        )}
     </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<NinePuzzle />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.board {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #5F5F22;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #FFFFC2;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.board div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top .25s, left .25s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex. Unfortunately, your suggested changes didn't work for me. It works only the first time you move a tile. Could you update my fiddle and post the link?

Comment: Sorry, there was even a third problem that I just fixed instinctively and forgot about. I made the other stuff more precisely correct too.

Comment: Yup. The biggest issue was the word-wrap logic I tried. Thanks!